# Web Component Is there any paper-checklist-filtering available?

Tags: web-component, polymer-1.0

Hi guys I'm looking for a Polymer-type checklist filtering element: http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/grid/functionality/filtering/checklist-filtering

[image: Checklist-filtering]

There would be a list with checkboxes and maybe a select all item on top. And then there will be like a paper-input on top that allows filtering of items below.

I can hack together a `checklist-filtering` component using `paper-input` and `iron-dropdown`. Maybe I would make something like this https://github.com/samccone/paper-typeahead, assuming that nothing is available as of now.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Most of existing and shared Custom Elements can be found at:

- [Component Kitchen](http://component.kitchen)
- [Custom Elements IO](https://customelements.io/)

There's also an alternate *Material Design* Library with elements that you could reuse to build your custom element :

- [ExpandJS](http://expandjs.com/)